# RuntimeException: setAudioSource failed / Got a deoptimization request on un-deoptimizable method

Tags: android, audio, android-audiorecord

What are conditions, when [`setAudioSource` method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder#setAudioSource(int)) is failing? I have fixed, compiled and ran [`MediaRecorder` example](https://www.javatpoint.com/android-mediarecorder-example). My fixes include, besides all, a permission check

```
    private static boolean recordPermitted(Activity activity) {

        Boolean recordPermission = ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(activity, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED;

        if (recordPermission) {
            return true;
        }

        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity, new String[]{Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO}, REQUESTCODE_RECORD_PERMISSION);
        return false;
    }
```

which is positive, although my code

```
        try {
            audiofile = File.createTempFile("sound", ".3gp", dir);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "external storage access error");
            return;
        }

        if( !recordPermitted(this) ) {
            Log.e(TAG, "was no record permission");
        }

        //Creating MediaRecorder and specifying audio source, output format, encoder & output format
        recorder = new MediaRecorder();
        recorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.MIC);
        recorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.THREE_GPP);
        recorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AMR_NB);
        recorder.setOutputFile(audiofile.getAbsolutePath());
        recorder.prepare();
        recorder.start();
```

fails and prints

```
W/recorderexampl: Got a deoptimization request on un-deoptimizable method void android.media.MediaRecorder.setAudioSource(int)
    Got a deoptimization request on un-deoptimizable method java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[])
W/recorderexampl: Got a deoptimization request on un-deoptimizable method java.lang.Object java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(java.lang.Object, java.lang.Object[])
D/AndroidRuntime: Shutting down VM
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.inthemoon.mediarecorderexample, PID: 1351
        ...
     Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: setAudioSource failed.
        at android.media.MediaRecorder.setAudioSource(Native Method)
        at com.inthemoon.mediarecorderexample.MainActivity.startRecording(MainActivity.java:62)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at android.view.View$DeclaredOnClickListener.onClick(View.java:6253) 
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:7438) 
        at android.view.View.performClickInternal(View.java:7415) 
        at android.view.View.access$3600(View.java:810) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:28286) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:223) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7523) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:592) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:941)
```

Why are examples and explanations so controversal for Android? What does "Got a deoptimization request on un-deoptimizable method" mean? How can I sure, that [`setAudioSource` method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder#setAudioSource(int)) will run on other devices